# Windows explorer 'date modified' has stopped updating. Any ideas why?

Tags: windows-10

I was using the date modified column to sort folders yesterday as I was batching actions on files within them and I was able to see which had completed by their modified date and time.

Today, none of the access dates are updating at all and the files inside show a much more recent modified date than its respective folder.

If anyone has any insight into why this is happening I'd be grateful.  Otherwise I have a few thousand folders to manually process!